# Rcpp sugar for NumericMatrix

Tags: r, rcpp

For `NumericVector`, I can subset a smaller `NumericVector` by using an `IntegerVector` that contains the positions to subset.

e.g. suppose `x<-c(1,2,2,3,4,5)`, `idx<-c(1,3,4)`, and `xsub<-x[idx]` which is `1 2 3`.

Within RCpp, I can simply use `xsub=x[idx]`.

Is there a similar way to subset the rows of a `NumericMatrix` using the `IntegerVector`?

For example, the following code `xmatsub=xmat(idx,_)` didn't work for me.

Comment: Be careful that indexing in C++ uses 0-based indices, so `x[idx]` will give you `2,3,4`.

Comment: Though outside of your requested Rcpp sugar requirement, arma (therefore `RcppArmadillo`) provides [submatrix views](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat) which allows you some power. It isn't sugar, and it certainly isn't Rcpp11/sugar, but it is nonetheless fairly powerful. One unfortunate thing I found is that I find it's generally difficult to do one portion of a function with `arma` and the rest with sugar. (I'm not a c++ wizard, so I'm likely missing something. I defer to @RomainFrancois for `Rcpp` correctness.)

Comment: Good point. Please make an answer out of it. The only slight incovenience is that you would have to make a copy of the data on the way out.

Comment: I tend to work in Armadillo objects for these types of operations.

Comment: @RomainFrancois, yes I had been subtracting 1 to get the 0 based indices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a way. You have to do it manually, which is not that complicated.

```
NumericMatrix res( idx.size(), m.rows() )  ;
for( int i=0; i<idx.size(); i++){
    res.row(i) = m.row(idx[i]-1) ; 
}
```